# Подскажите методы выведения на экран с помощью блока If

Tags: java

Нужно сделать так, что если наступает определённое время, то на экране выводится, что принимает другой врач. Можно ли написать как-то с помощью примера ниже?

```
if (i > 16:00) {
    принимает другой врач к примеру
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Это делается довольно просто:

```
LocalTime changeTime = LocalTime.of(16, 0);

if (LocalTime.now().isBefore(changeTime))
   System.out.println("принимает первый врач");
else
   System.out.println("принимает второй врач");
```

Если же вы хотите это делать асинхронно, то можно запустить таймер:

```
LocalTime changeTime = LocalTime.of(16, 0);
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
long delay;
if (now.isAfter(changeTime))
        delay =
                changeTime.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY)
                        - now.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY)
                        + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
else
        delay =
                changeTime.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY)
                        - now.getLong(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY);


new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("принимает второй врач");
                }
            },
            delay, TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
```

Он будет выводить строку раз в сутки, в `16:00`

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше использовать библиотеку [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). Она не очень простая, но очень гибкая. Примере можно поискать [тут](https://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/).

Либо посмотреть в сторону [Spring sheduler](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). Стоит обратить внимание на параметр `cron`, синтаксис схож с Quart, подробнее можно посмотреть [тут](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html).

В вашем случае крон должен получится какой-то такой `"0 0 16 * * *"`